# If condition is always false in second loop for jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm fetching the user data then fetching user plan and then comparing them to show user wise plan list.

```
if data.user_list[0]
 each user_list,i in data.user_list[0]
    tr
      td.center img(src='admin/img/details_open.png')
      td #{user_list.first_name} #{user_list.last_name}
      td #{user_list.email}
      td.hidden-phone #{user_list.occupation}
      td.center.hidden-phone #{user_list.city}
      td.center.hidden-phone #{user_list.medical_condition}
    if data.user_plan_list
        each user_plan,j in data.user_plan_list
            if (user_plan.member_id===user_list._id)
                | in if #{user_plan.member_id} "---" #{user_list._id} 
                br
            else
                | in else #{user_plan.member_id} "---" #{user_list._id} 
                br
```

Comment: Please ask specific question and not just copy paste the code here.

Comment: Ok see my last if condition it always goes to else, even if i have correct data to compare

Comment: You use strict comparison ("==="). Are you sure, that both id's have same data type?

Comment: Yes they have both are ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

Added a toString() function to convert the object type to string for compare

```
if data.user_plan_list
  -var count=1;
     each user_plan,i in data.user_plan_list
        if user_plan.member_id.toString() == user_list._id.toString()
```